# Android, Can't initialize an Object after querying data's from Firebase

Tags: android, database, firebase, object, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a simple old-style browser game like Tanoth/OGame but on android. I use Cloud Fire Store database, but i have a problem.
After the login activity, i pass in the intent the String containing the character name of the user. With that i want to get the my PGCharacter Object from the database with a simple query. At the beginning of the class i declare a PGCharacter variable but i don't initialize it.

In onCreate method, i initialize the database and the collection where all my characters are stored. I create a Document Reference with the ExtraString in Intent, since all my documents IDs are the same as the player usernames. After that, i make a query and if i find the snapshot i want to initialize my PGCharacter object with my Snapshot result. The problem is that every time i want to print something of my Object it crashes. I hope i well explained the problem.
How can i solve it? I even tried adding an external function but it didn't work.
P.s for my tests i'm using an already existing player

Heres my Class code:

```
package com.github.albertocoder97.archadia;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

public class CharacterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseFirestore db;
private CollectionReference characterCollection;

private PGCharacter pgCharacter;

private TextView usernameTextView;
private TextView goldTextView;
private TextView gemsTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_character);

    //Initialize the database
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    //Get characters database
    characterCollection = db.collection("characters");

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String characterName = intent.getStringExtra("CHARACTER_NAME");

    Log.i("myFilter", "Intent input: " + characterName);

    //Initializing PGCharacter Object
    DocumentReference charDocReference = characterCollection.document(characterName);
    Log.i("myFilter", "ID: " + charDocReference.getId());
    charDocReference.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            Log.i("myFilter", "Inner Gold DocumentSnapshot: " + documentSnapshot.get("gold").toString());
            setPGCharacter(documentSnapshot);
        }
    });

}




public void setPGCharacter(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
    PGCharacter temp = snapshot.toObject(PGCharacter.class);
    pgCharacter = temp;
}
```

}

P.P.s i tried loggin the snapshot.getData() and i get all my PGCharacter data, if anyone asks, in my PGCharacter class i have a public empty constructor and all the gets for each property.

Comment: problem::PGCharacter class i have a public empty constructor and all the gets for each property.Important: Each custom class must have a public constructor that takes no arguments. In addition, the class must include a public getter for each property.

Comment: My class has a public constructor that takes no arguments, and also has all public getters for all properties. I wrote it in the post :) The problem isn't that it doesn't create the object. If i put it in a temp variable, it works. The problem is that it doesn't work if i put it in "private PGCharacter pgCharacter;"

Comment: that's because you have declared it twice

Comment: Where? I have declared once before the onCreation and that's it. Where did i declared it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line

```
pgCharacter = temp;
```

Comment: If i remove it, how can i pass the object to pgCharacter? I can't access temp from outer methods tho.

Comment: just try it and tell me if it fixed it

Comment: It doesn't crash but pgCharacter is not initialized and i can't access temp

Comment: I want to get the datas from the object i retrieved from the database to set display texts. The point is that if i try to initialize pgCharacter from inside the query, it crashes. If i try to use another function, i can't access the variable temp that's inside.

Comment: you can't do that that's why it crashes,in the setText you can only put text not an object

Comment: I fixed it changing pgCharacter from private to public, thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: remember to cast it if you are going to use it inside setText